# Re-enable autoescape after it has been disabled in Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm writing a simple blog using Flask and Jinja2, and I want to use HTML tags in my posts.
So I was disabled the *autoescape* in my templates like this:

```
{{ post.body|safe }}
```

But when I writing something like `>>> print()` or `it's`, however I don't want to escape them myself, I want to enable the *autoescape* again. Is there anything like a HTML tag to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to use HTML in your `post.body` - then you have to deal with the fact that some symbols have to be escaped in HTML, e.g. `>` should be `&gt;`. The second option is using `<pre>`. The third option is post-processing the body, so that the code parts like `>>>` are automatically escaped. For example:

```
class Post:
    body = "<span><code>>>> print('Hello world')</code></span>"

    @property
    def html_body(self):
        # 1. Locate all <code>...</code> blocks
        # 2. Convert the text in them to proper HTML
        ...
        return processed_body

    # which should return 
    # "<span><code>&gt;&gt;&gt; print(&apos;Hello world&apos;)</code></span>"
```

Comment: Hmm...So maybe I need post-processing the body, like escape the code parts?

Comment: Okay, understand now :)